# GitLab CI/CD fails to connect with GCP using Workload Identity Federation and ID Tokens

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, cicd

I am trying to run Terraform from GitLab CI/CD to deploy assets in GCP and would like to use Workload Identity Federations and ID Tokens (since CI_JOB_JWT_V2 is deprecated). My current GitLab CI/CD code is as follows:

```
 gcp-auth:
  stage: prepare
  image: google/cloud-sdk:slim
  id_tokens:
    GCP_TOKEN:
      aud: //iam.googleapis.com/projects/MyProjectID/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/MyPoolID/providers/MyProvider
  script:
    - echo ${GCP_TOKEN} > .ci_job_jwt_file
    - gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config "${GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER}"
      --service-account="${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"
      --output-file=.gcp_temp_cred.json
      --credential-source-file=.ci_job_jwt_file
    - gcloud config set project ${GOOGLE_PROJECT}
    - gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json
    - gcloud storage buckets list
```

However, when running the pipeline, the last "Bucket List" command crashes with the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.storage.buckets.list) There was a problem refreshing
> your current auth tokens: ('Error code invalid_request: Invalid value
> for "audience". This value should be the full resource name of the
> Identity Provider. See
> https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/sts/rest/v1/TopLevel/token
> for the list of possible formats.',
> '{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid value for
> \"audience\". This value should be the full resource name of the
> Identity Provider. See
> https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/sts/rest/v1/TopLevel/token
> for the list of possible formats."}')

The `.gcp_temp_cred.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/gitlab-gitlab",
  "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt",
  "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
  "credential_source": {
    "file": ".ci_job_jwt_file"
  },
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/MyServiceAccountEmail:generateAccessToken"
}
```

It seems there is an issue with the "audience" value for the ID Token configuration. Can anyone help me identify what's wrong with my configuration and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your ID token is set like this:

```
id_tokens:
  GITLAB_TOKEN:
    aud: https://gitlab.domain.com #the same audience you've set in GCP
```

Next make sure the `GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER` variable is set like this:

```
projects/<project-number>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<your-pool>/providers/<your-provider>
```

Please note that you need to use the project number **and NOT** the project ID.

Fully working code:

```yaml
image: google/cloud-sdk:slim
id_tokens:
  GITLAB_TOKEN:
    aud: https://gitlab.mydomain.com
variables:
  GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER: projects/897387698213/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gitlab-pool/providers/gitlab
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL: wif-gitlab@my-mega-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
before_script:
  - echo ${GITLAB_TOKEN} > ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.ci_job_jwt_file
  - gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config ${GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER}
    --service-account="${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}"
    --output-file=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.gcp_temp_cred.json
    --credential-source-file=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.ci_job_jwt_file
  - gcloud auth login --cred-file=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.gcp_temp_cred.json
  - gcloud auth list
  - gcloud compute instances list --project=my-mega-project
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I just tried that but still getting:

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: ('Error code invalid_grant: Unable to parse the ID Token.', '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Unable to parse the ID Token."}')

Comment: @exStas unfortunately not. For the time i went back to just using Service-Accounts.

Comment: Same issue for me with id_tokens "Unable to parse the ID Token", althought it works with the deprecated CI_JOB_JWT_V2. Has someone solved this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I had followed a troubleshooting approach for some previous issue and I had added following line inside with: key

```
token_format: 'access_token'
```

Once I removed this line it got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Google Cloud Console UI to create my provider and pool and apparently I had left out the attribute mapping of `aud` when creating it.

[image]

Once I added this mapping, it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was just battling with this error from Google Identity Federation myself (on Github using google-github-actions/auth@v0) and came back as I found the solution

The audience doesn't include the `//iam.googleapis.com/` part so just set `GCP_TOKEN` to `projects/MyProjectID/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/MyPoolID/providers/MyProvider`

I found [this helpful command](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine/issues/247#issuecomment-1326181666) from a Github thread which might be helpful if anyone else needs to find their audience

```
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools providers describe "my-provider" \
  --project="${PROJECT_ID}" \
  --location="global" \
  --workload-identity-pool="my-pool" \
  --format="value(name)"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Just tried that, but keep getting the same error.